# Export Mailbox as PST in Exchange Admin Center

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, mailbox

I am trying to export a few mailboxes as .pst files in Microsoft's Exchange Admin Center:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-import-and-export/export-procedures?view=exchserver-2019

Under Roles > Admin Roles > Organization Management (role group) – The admin user is assigned, and the permissions include Mailbox Import Export.

I have logged in and out multiple times.

However, when selecting a mailbox, I still cannot see the option to 'download as .pst'.

What else do I need to do to export a mailbox as a pst file?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Which server are your mailboxes locating on? On-prem Exchange Server or Exchange Online(Office 365)?

**A.** If it's on-prem server, can you export the .pst of your mailboxes by running the following command in the EMS(Exchange Management Shell)?

```
New-MailboxExportRequest
```

**a.** If the command can't be recognized, perhaps the RBAC permissions haven't worked yet, try running the following command in the PowerShell and then log out/in again to see if there is any differerence:

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -SecurityGroup "Organization Management" -Role "Mailbox Import Export"
Add-RoleGroupMember -Identity "Organization Management" -Member <User>
```

**b.** If the issue only happened in EAC, maybe some browser cache caused this issue, I think you could try accessing EAC in incognito mode or using another browser and see if it still exists.

**B.** If it's Exchange Online, because the command **[New-MailboxExportRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboxexportrequest?view=exchange-ps)** which has the same feature with **`Export to a PST file`** is available in only Exchange 2010/2013/2016/2019, the option will not appear even if you assign enough permissions(**Mailbox Import Export** role or **eDiscovery Management Administrator**). To export the data of your mailboxes to .pst files, you can try doing an **[eDiscovery Content Search (Content/Compliance search)](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/how-to/export-office-365-mailboxes-to-pst/)** and download the .pst file from the search result.